# problems for Category Policy Spec with pundit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pundit

so I do the association of the categories and posts through categorizations.
And i'm trying to restrict the access with pundit gem and testing with RSpec for to show by a category the posts. Because with this association I have something like:
c = Category.first
c.posts

and i'm showing the posts by a category.

And i need some help.

my categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show]

  def show
    authorize @category, :show?
  end

  private

  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations

  validates :name,
                  presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 30 },
                  uniqueness: true
end
```

app/views/categories/show.html.slim

```
= title("Category - #{@category.name}")
#category.text-center
  h1 Category: <small>#{@category.name}</small>

  - if @category.posts
    #category.posts
      - @category.posts.each do |post|
        .row.col-md-12
          .caption
            h2 = link_to post.title, post
            p = link_to post.subtitle, post
            small = "by : #{post.author}"
          hr
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    root 'application#index'

    resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :categories

    resources :users do
      member do
        patch :archive
      end
    end
  end

  devise_for :users

  root "posts#index"

  resources :posts, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
  resources :categories, only: [:show]
end
```

category_policy.rb

```
class CategoryPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      resolve
    end
  end

  def show?
    user.try(:admin?) || record.post.has_member?(user)
  end
end
```

category_policy_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CategoryPolicy do
  context "permissions" do
    subject        { CategoryPolicy.new(user, category) }
    let(:user)     { create(:user) }
    let(:post)     { create(:post) }
    let(:category) { create(:category) }

    context "for anonymous users" do
      let(:user) { nil }

      it { should_not permit_action :show }
    end

    context "for viewers of the post" do
      before { assign_role!(user, :viewer, post) }

      it { should permit_action :show }
    end

    context "for editors of the post" do
      before { assign_role!(user, :editor, post) }

      it { should permit_action :show }
    end

    context "for managers of the post" do
      before { assign_role!(user, :manager, post) }

      it { should permit_action :show }
    end

    context "for managers of other posts" do
      before do
         assign_role!(user, :manager, create(:post))
      end

      it { should_not permit_action :show }
    end

    context "for administrators" do
      let(:user) { create(:user, :admin) }

      it  { should permit_action :show }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using this matcher.
pundit_matcher.rb

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :permit_action do |action|
  match do |policy|
    policy.public_send("#{action}?")
  end

  failure_message do |policy|
    "#{policy.class} does not allow #{policy.user || "nil"} to " +
      "perform :#{action}? on #{policy.record}."
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |policy|
    "#{policy.class} does not forbid #{policy.user || "nil"} from " +
      "performing :#{action}? on #{policy.record}."
  end
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_many :roles, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

  mount_base64_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

  validates :title,
              presence: true,
              length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 },
              uniqueness: true
  validates :subtitle,
              length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :content,
              presence: true,
              length: { minimum: 30 }
  validates :attachment, file_size: { less_than: 1.megabytes }


  def has_member?(user)
    roles.exists?(user_id: user)
  end

  [:manager, :editor, :viewer].each do |role|
    define_method "has_#{role}?" do |user|
      roles.exists?(user_id: user, role: role)
    end
  end

end
```

roler.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  def self.available_roles
    %w(manager editor viewer)
  end
end
```

When I try to run the:

```
rspec spec/policies/category_policy_spec.rb
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: user.try(:admin?) || record.post.has_member?(user)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<Category:0x007fc61bfdbf40>
       Did you mean?  posts
```

It's ok show this posts by category on show, or I need to switch for index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, your Category model doesn't have a `post` method, it only has `posts`.  This is because Category has_many posts.  Because of that `record.post.has_member?(user)` in your Category policy doesn't make any sense (`record` is a Category instance).  Since Category doesn't appear to have a direct relationship to users, and your roles are associated with users and posts.

It's unclear to me what the purpose of your Category policy actually is, unless it's to only allow a user to see categories if they already have a post that uses that category? If that's the case then you need to change the policy to actually check if any of those exist.

Comment: My purpose was to show the posts by a category.
But I was thinking this is not a good idea. 
And rather then do this the best idea is just show the posts by category who will be published with no restrict access.
Thank you for reply and edit Thomas Walpole

Comment: @rld Yes, but your permissions are purely based on the posts, not on the categories.  ie - a user can be allowed to view one post of category "tech" but not a second post of category "tech".  With that model asking the question "Can a user view a category?" doesn't really make sense.  If the question you really want the policy to enforce is "can a user view any of the posts in a specific category" then you need to change the query to actually ask that question and then enforce filtering of the posts in that category for the scope.

Comment: Yes the users can view more posts with a category. I do the categories with has many through categorizations.

But I will do for watch just  these posts who was published. And the restriction will be just for posts.

Thank you  for reply @Thomas Walpole